# OpenCV Kalman sequential measurements

Tags: matlab, opencv, math, kalman-filter

I'm tracking the position of two lines detected in camera stream in OpenCV. Right now, I'm using a separate Kalman filter for each line, but their positions are highly correlated—they may drift apart very slowly, whereas the measurement (line detection) is on the other hand very noisy.

Due to the correlation, I want to combine both lines to be tracked by the same filter. If done right, that should significantly decrease the influence of false positive edge detections because they would jump relatively to the other line; on the other hand, both lines shifting position together would be reasonably expected to have high influence.

My problem is that the lines are detected periodically, not every frame, and **generally not simultaneously**. The usual case is that the left line would be detected only, or the right one (or none); rarely both lines would be detected at the same time.

Right now wit I call `predict()` on every frame for each line's filter, and if a line is detected and also do `correct()`. However, if I want to use the same filter for both lines, how can I only do a partial correct for that line? I was thinking one step might be to zero out the other line's components in `measurementMatrix` for that particular measurement, but what about `measurementNoiseCov`?

In [this document](http://biorobotics.ri.cmu.edu/papers/sbp_papers/integrated3/kleeman_kalman_basics.pdf) I see the following:

> **Sequential Measurement Processing**
>   If the measurement noise vector components are uncorrelated then state update can be carried out one measurement at a time.
>   Thus matrix inversions are replaced by scalar inversions.
>   Procedure: state prediction as before
>   - scalar measurements are processed sequentially (in any order)
>   - using scalar measurement equations.

Is this equivalent (if I assume uncorrelated measurement noise is a good enough approximation)? Else, how would I need to modify `correct()` in OpenCV?